# How to install bitmapped *.fon and *.bdf fonts on Lion?

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I want to install some rare bitmapped<sup>1</sup> fonts on a Lion<sup>2</sup> system.  I have not been able to find these fonts in formats that Font Book will immediately recognize.  I would like to know if there's a way to convert or re-package these fonts in such a way that Font Book will accept.

One of the fonts (["pcsansi"](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_cropsource/downloads/config/eclipse%203.6/pcsansi.fon/)) is a single file with extension `fon`.

The other one (["Terminus"](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/)) consists of multiple files with extension `bdf`.

(FWIW, at least one of these fonts, Terminus, is a  font, but for all I know both of them are.)

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

PS: I am particularly keen on installing Terminus.  Of the two fonts, it is the only one for which I was able to find any documentation at all.  (See link above.)  In fact, it comes with a `./configure` + `make` + `make install` installation procedure, but the latter step only gzips and relocates a set of *.psf and *.pcf files generated from the *.bdf files during the `make` step.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Yes, I am aware of the fact that not many people like bitmapped fonts.  I still want to install these fonts.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> This is the latest OS X version that will run on the hardware.</sup>

Comment: I'm no real fonts expert, but Fontographer or similar from http://www.fontlab.com might be the thing you need

Comment: @kjo Can't help you with your question but Terminus.ttf is available [here](http://misc.nybergh.net/pub/fonts/terminus/ttf/)! Only Terminus worked for me though. None of the "Mac-OS-X optimized" faces linked there nore the regular TerminalBold worked for me.

Comment: @klanomath: +++ Thanks a lot!!!  That's quite a find.  I had the same problem as you did with the OS X-optimized version, but the regular version is nice enough.  To think that this unique gem of a font is on the verge of disappearance boggles the mind.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/). My brother used it a few years ago when he needed to design fonts for use on Mac & Windows machines. Website claims it can open .bdf files, but no mention of .fon files.